# How to keep vertical scrollbar always at the end of the jtable

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

What i want is i want to have a scrollbar always at the last row.sometimes i have morethan 60 rows.that time i need to have a scrollbar at the end of the 60th row.

I manually added rows and columns in jtable in my program.
Any way is there to do this?
Please give some simple example.
i am beginner to jtable.

Answer (score 1):

on your button click listener add this code:

```
JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
vertical.setValue( vertical.getMaximum() );
```

and you will have your scroll panel always to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you update your table, you could do:

```
JTable tbl; // your table
tbl.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, tbl.getHeight() - 1, tbl.getWidth(), 1));
```